# <.Subcharts.alertmanager>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.alertmanager Error while install prometheus on kubernetes cluster

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

helm upgrade -i prometheus prometheus-community/prometheus   --namespace prometheus   --set alertmanager.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2",server.persistentVolume.storageClass="gp2"
Release "prometheus" does not exist. Installing it now.
Error: template: prometheus/templates/_helpers.tpl:80:47: executing "prometheus.alertmanager.fullname" at <.Subcharts.alertmanager>: nil pointer evaluating interface {}.alertmanager

I have tried to clone the chart and fix _helpers.tpl file but it somehow keeps on throwing different error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when installing Prometheus chart with Helm 3.2.4. Issue resolved after I upgraded Helm to 3.13.2, latest version as of now.
https://github.com/helm/helm/releases/tag/v3.13.2